# How to show new content using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

well basically this is the [CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/ghs3J/3/)
but for some reason it wont show the the new content, if someone please help me, i would appreciate that.

I want to be able to show a new content after clicking the button,
please see the full code

html

```
<section class="showr">
    <a rel="external" href="#button" id="button" class="button">&#xF011;</a>
    <span></span>
</section>
<p class="hidn"> Welcome To a Crazy World</p>`
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('on');
    });
});
```

Comment: Clicking the button adds or removed the class "on". How do you expect it to know to show something else?

Comment: Show what content? It seems to work just as expected, to show the paragraph toggle the `hidn` class on that as well.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ghs3J/4/

Comment: that $ code is basically just for the button, i got confused trying to add a show function to the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything within `$('#button').click(function(){ ... });` is executed when the button is clicked so you need to add code in that function that shows the other element.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('on');
        $('p.hidn').show();
    });
});
```

But perhaps you mean you want to toggle that content?

```
$('p').toggleClass('hidn');
```

NB, this will affect other paragraphs on the page. You might want to give the content an ID and target that.

Comment: i tried both codes, and (p.hidn).show works perfectly, but after i click the button it wont disappear, however toggleclass works just fine but it affects css

Comment: nvm, i figured that just editing in html instead of the stylesheet works just fine

Comment: I used .show() in the first example because you didn't specify it should disappear if the button is clicked again.